# How to make ListView inside ViewPager scrollable and rest all headers and footers fixed?

Tags: android, android-layout

My `ViewPager` has a `ListView`, which I want to make scrollable and rest all items fixed. How can I do that? Would scrollable help me? If yes how can I do that? Also I hope adding scrollable for `ViewPager` won't reduce the performance

Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#85929B"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="452dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainheader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:background="#0a2436">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/subheader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="52dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/my_highlight_drawable"
                    android:src="@drawable/back" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/inboxheader"
                    android:layout_width="2dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
                    android:background="#85929B"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                    android:paddingTop="15dip" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="No Data Available"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center" >


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/previous"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Previous"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/submitdata"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

              </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is it curently doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this hierarchy, scrollview inside which u can have the view pager

```
<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager" />

</ScrollView>
```